# dropdown menu for ipad tapping

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a css3 based drop down menu.It works based on hover mentioned in css. But I need to make this work on ipad, since i pad doesn't consider hover the dropdown will nt work on ipad.

Is there any property to mention for ipad. It will be great if we can alter my existingg css only.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>menu</title>
<style>
/* Main menu */
.menu
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;  
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}
.menu li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
}
.menu a 
{
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
.menu li:hover > a
{
    color: #fafafa;
}
.menu li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

/* Sub-menu */
.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;    
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);   
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu ul ul
{
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
}

.menu ul li
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;  
}
.menu ul li:last-child
{   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}
.menu ul a
{    
    padding: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
.menu ul a:hover
{
    background: #0186ba;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}

.menu ul li:first-child > a
{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li:first-child a:hover
{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

.menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover
{
    border-right-color: #04acec; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}


.menu ul li:last-child > a
{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
.menu:after 
{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

</style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Categories</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu 4menu2menu2menu2menu2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying a class to the li when the touchstart and touchend events are fired. And use that (.hover) as well as the :hover pseudo event in your css

eg in your js:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $(".menu li a").bind('touchstart', function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    });

    $(".menu li a").bind('touchend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
}
```

Comment: You can do `navigator.userAgent.match( /iP(hone|od|ad)/ )` in the if statement instead of what you did.